# How to use variables from a Bash shell script in Matlab m-file

Tags: bash, matlab, loops, text, while-loop

I've inherited an m-file that calls the function:

```
function conditions(varargin)
```

This requires me to type a series of names when running the m-file. E.g.,:

```
conditions('c01','c02','c03')
```

I also have a text file (conditions.txt) that contains all conditions names, one conditions per line. e.g.,:

```
'c01'
'c02'
'c03'
etc...
```

Is there a way to automate conditions.m through the Bash shell by running through each line of the text file, one line at a time?

Comment: Why Bash? Just use MATLAB to read the file and call `conditions()`, easier, no?

Comment: I'd like to not need to leave Bash.

Comment: Could you explain why you’d like to not leave Bash? Do you want to not have to learn how to do this in MATLAB, or do you have some other constraints? Doing this in MATLAB would be a lot easier, and a lot more efficient. It’s hard for me to recommend a solution to a problem I think is the wrong one...

Comment: It's part of an analysis pipeline that is largely automated through Bash script, and I'm more familiar with Bash. I didn't want to change the M-file. But if it is much easier doing this through matlab I'm happy to take all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're happy to take other suggestions as well, I'm going to suggest you do this through a simple MATLAB script. MATLAB takes a while to start up, so it is quite inefficient to start MATLAB anew for each "condition".

I'm going to assume that your text file example is a simplification, maybe you have multiple parameters per line, and need to pass each of them as an argument to the `conditions` function. For example the file `conditions.txt` could contain:

```
'c01',5,false
'c02',100,true,0,'foo'
...
```

and you'd want to generate the calls

```
conditions('c01',5,false)
conditions('c02',100,true,0,'foo')
...
```

The following code accomplishes this:

```
f = fopen('conditions.txt','rt');
while true
   data = fgetl(f);
   if isequal(data,-1), break, end
   eval('conditions(',data,')')
end
fclose(f);
exit
```

You could save that as an M-file script (e.g. `runconditions.m`), and execute it from bash as follows:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r runconditions
```

---

`eval` is evil, in general, but in this case it's the same as what you'd be doing from the Bash script [in Christian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51475532/7328782). The only difference with that answer is that you avoid starting up MATLAB repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

At least on windows you can call matlab functions from batch like this: `matlab -wait -r 'conditions(%var%)'`

So your bash looping should be solvable with a code snipped like this:

```
while read p; do
 matlab -wait -r 'conditions($p)'
done <yourfile.txt
```

Or any other looping style of your choice:
[Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. While the output indicates it is running through the text file line by line, it only performs the function for the very first input (i.e., line 1).

Comment: So if you add a `echo $p` into the while loop it shows each line?

Comment: echo indicates it is only using the first line of the list: 'c01'. The bash shell output of the MATLAB script suggests that for the remaining lines of the text file it is simply entering that line into MATLAB. I.e., >> ans = c02  >> ans == c03, and so on.

Comment: And you are sure, that you have no issues with multiply quotation marks? Not that you use the same type within your file and your matlab call. 
Beware: Since Matlab 2017 "asdasd" is a string, while 'asdt' is a char array.

Comment: I don't believe so. All lines in my text file are entered with single quotes. And the function picks up the first line, just not the rest.

Comment: You might want to remove `-wait` from the call to MATLAB. It proceses the first line then waits for MATLAB to terminate, so it doesn’t get to do the other lines.

Comment: I removed `-wait` as Matlab doesn't recognize it.

Comment: My workaround has been to simply edit the text file and include all condition names on the same line separated by commas. I.e.,'c01', 'c02', 'c03', etc..  My working script is:  
`while read p; do  
matlab -nosplash -r "conditions($p)"
echo "Completed for following conditions: $p"  
done < conditions.txt`

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just assumed that if someone executes something from bash, they also want to have control over their return-codes and hence use explit exit(rc) calls.

Comment: Ah, my understanding of `-wait` was wrong. It's a Windows-only argument that makes it so `matlab` doesn't return immediately, but waits until MATLAB finishes. What is missing here is the `exit` at the end of the command, MATLAB starts up, and never finishes. The command needs to be `matlab -r "conditions($p); exit"` (note: double-quotes, as single quotes don't allow variable expansion).

Comment: @CrisLuengo your script certainly works - matlab now cycles through each line of the text file and executes the M-file correctly. Although, it does require that Matlab restart for each new line of the text file, which is time costly and slow.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Oh, it was in regards to `matlab -r "conditions($p); exit"`

Comment: @user240917: ah, yes, indeed, that will work, but start MATLAB anew for each line. There is no way AFAIK to pass commands to a running MATLAB session from a Bash script. MATLAB comes with a Python package that lets you do just that from Python, but I haven’t heard of a similar thing for Bash. A MATLAB script would be more efficient just for this.